# special characters in droidText - Android

Tags: special-characters, itext, android-droidtext

I need to use special characters like "ç", "á"... but nothing works.

Part of the code:

```
Paragraph title = new Paragraph();

com.lowagie.text.Font fontTitle= FontFactory.getFont("Arial", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 15, Font.BOLD);

title.add(new Paragraph("ç", fontTtile));

document.add(title);
```

Using IDENTITY_H and EMBEDDED the pdf doesn't work, but if I just use ("Arial", 15, Font.BOLD) it works (special characters don't).

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: (How) did you define "Arial" in the FontFactory? Do you ship arial.ttf with your APK? I think "Arial" wasn't found and Helvetica was used instead. The standard type 1 font Helvetica doesn't know how to draw a "ç". How did you compile the code? Because "ç" in your source code might not compile to "ç" in byte code. Also: DroidText? Why on earth would you use that? Those guys (ab?)use my name (I'm the Lowagie you refer to in your code). Read http://lowagie.com/itext2 and use http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextg instead.